# Different definitions of the Hopf Invariant

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I have seen two different definitions of the Hopf invariant, and I wanted to know if they are equivalent, and if so, how I would go about showing that they are equivalent.

If we fix a map $f:S^{2p-1}\to S^p$
then Milnor's Topology from a Differentiable Viewpoint defines the Hopf invariant of $f$ to be the linking number $l(f^{-1}(y),f^{-1}(z))$ where $y\neq z$ are regular values of $f$ (and as an exercise, we rove that this value is independent of our choice of $y$ and $z$).

The second definition is to take $\omega$ a volume form on $S^p$ and choose $\eta$ such that $f^*\omega=d\eta$. Then the Hopf invariant of $f$ is the integral $\displaystyle\int_{S^{2p-1}}\eta\wedge f^*\omega$

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent, but proving that is not easy. You have to understand first why Poincaré duality tells you that you can compute the intersection number of two compact oriented submanifolds by cup (or wedge) product of their Poincaré dual cohomology classes. This is then a slight modification (computing linking number as an intersection number).

Comment: You have some typos, by the way. $f$ should be mapping $S^{2p-1}$ to $S^p$, and then $n$ should be $p$.

Comment: I've fixed both the edits.  Is there a source with a more detailed proof?

Comment: As I said, you need quite a bit of background. But you can see a detailed discussion on pp. 227-239 of Bott and Tu's *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*.

Comment: Thank you! Some of the details was beyond me, but this was interesting.